# XCode/iOS: NSCoding - persistence of object graph with two arrays of common objects

Tags: xcode, ios, nscoding

I have two classes which look like this in barebones form:

```
@interface GraphNode {
    NSMutableArray *edges;
}

@implementation GraphNode

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        edges = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"edges"];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder {
    [coder encodeObject:edges forKey:@"edges"];
}

@end

@interface GraphEdges {
  NSMutableArray *edges;
}

@implementation GraphEdges

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        edges = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"edges"];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder {
    [coder encodeObject:edges forKey:@"edges"];
}

@end
```

You'll notice they seem to express the same behaviour - encoding/decoding an NSMutableArray whose contents are objects of a type GraphEdge which implements NSCoding. The difference between the classes in practise is that GraphEdges creates edges in its `edges` property, while GraphNode adds to its own `edges` only references to already-existing GraphEdge instances in GraphEdges.edges .

My issue is that when decoding GraphNode and GraphEdges objects the object graph is not maintained since each class creates its own versions of the original GraphEdge objects stored in the `edges` property for each class.

I tried to do an encodeConditionalObject on the whole NSMutableArray *edges in GraphNode while keeping the encode in GraphEdges unconditional, but unsurprisingly this simply fails to encode GraphNode.edges as the condition is placed on the array itself, not its objects.

Is the solution to iterate through the arrays in both cases, and perform conditional encoding on each `edges` member for GraphNode but unconditional encoding for each member of `edges` in GraphEdges?

Any advice is appreciated, many thanks.

Comment: What does this have to do with Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you're archiving GraphNode and GraphEdges objects separately. Combine all related GraphNode and GraphEdges objects in some sort of container, maybe 'Graph,' so that they all become part of the same object graph. I believe that NSKeyedArchiver will then archive each object only once.

Comment: You were right, I gave them a common ancestor which implemented NSCoding and the problem was solved. Many thanks, Caleb.